# Minimizing Javascript and HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client-side-scripting

I developed a custom tool for my clients in which they can submit feedback to a central database.

I have a long HTML and JavaScript code which the clients paste on their web site and the tool appears on the website.

My problem is how can I minimize this code? I have seen chat tools which require to paste only a few lines of code and it appears on the browser.

Below is my code and I need to generate a small portion of code out of it.

```
<div id='htmlfeedback-container-more'>
<a id='lnkdivFeedBackPage1' href='#'>FeedBack</a> | <a id='lnkdivFeedBackPage2' href='#'>Settings</a><br /><br />
<div id='divFeedBackPage1'>
<div id='content' class='content'></div>
<p>Please give a short description of your feedback. You can also highlight or blackout parts of the screen.</p>
<p>Note: Click on highlighted areas to disappear </p>
<form id='htmlfeedback-form'>
<p> <span>Marker:</span><input type='radio' name='marker' value='rgba(255,255,255,0)' style='width:10%' checked> Highlight <input type='radio' name='marker' value='rgb(0,0,0)' style='width:10%'> Black out    </p>
<p><span>Name or E-mail:</span> <input type='text' name='email' id='htmlfeedback-input-email' style='width:88%'/></p>
<p><span>Short description:</span> <textarea name='description' id='htmlfeedback-input-description'></textarea></p>
<p><input type='submit' id='htmlfeedback-submit' value='Send' style='background-color:#5547ec'><input type='reset' id='htmlfeedback-reset' value='Reset' style='width:30%;background-color:#5547ec'></p>
</form></div>
<div id='divFeedBackPage2'>
<p>Changes will take effect through all the instances of the tool if you have added the control in multiple locations.</p>
<form id='frmfeedBackSettings-form'>
<p><span>Title:</span><input type='text' name='text' id='txtfeedBackTitle' style='width: 88%' /></p>
<p><span>Color:</span><input type='text' name='text' id='txtfeedBackColor' /></p>
<input type='submit' id='btnSubmitFeedbackSettings' value='Submit'/>
</form></div></div></div>
<div id='divWaitMsg' style='display:none; color:blue; font-size:20px' class='centered'>Please Wait....</div>
```

Comment: If the client's are in a PHP or ASP.Net environment, you can make an include or UserControl that will let them paste a single line.  Another option would be to put the above HTML in a page, and the associated JavaScript on your site, then the clients can paste an iframe line into their page that loads your HTML.  A clearer picture of the environment, and where the database is in relation to the client's website would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that some people do what you are trying to do with only a couple lines of code is with HTML iFrames,

Like

`<noscript>Enable Javascript to get full functionality of this <a href="http://www.freeshoutbox.net/">shoutbox</a><br /></noscript><iframe src="http://CodeLuca.freeshoutbox.net/" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

or

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DBXZWB_dNsw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

If you want to make one you just have to make your form on a blank page, then make an iframe that links to it.

Good Luck!

Luca

Comment: iframes are not an `html5` feature, they have been around forever. How do you substantiate that that most people use this approach?

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, yeah it's not an html5 feature, edited that, not sure why I said that. Also I have used lots of services like this, or have had to embed things, and they usually use iframes... Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a js code inject this into the dom where it is required and they can add it by placing a script tag.

`<script src="feedback-form.js"></script>` and the feedback form would inject the html content.